# Somehow getting a null in my array when i pass a function with parameters that dont involve the array

Tags: arrays, c, null

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBoardRow(int x, char arr[]) {
    printf("%d ", x);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf("%c", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
    
int whosTurn(int round, int *playerNo, int *opp, char proposedcoordinate[]){
    if (round%2 == 0){
        printf("Player 2 turn: ");
        scanf("%s", proposedcoordinate);
        *playerNo = 2;
        *opp = 1;
    }
    else if (round%2 != 0){ 
        *playerNo = 1;
        *opp = 2;
        printf("Player 1 turn: ");
        scanf("%s", proposedcoordinate);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char row0[] = {' ', '*', '*', ' '};
    char row1[] = {'*', '*', '*', '*'};
    char row2[] = {'*', '*', '*', '*'};
    char row3[] = {' ', '*', '*', ' '};

    //print start empty board
    printf("  abcd\n");
    printBoardRow(0, row0);
    printBoardRow(1, row1);
    printBoardRow(2, row2);
    printBoardRow(3, row3);
    
    //while game not dead, ask input, check and print board after each turn
    int turn = 0;
    for (int i=1;i<5;i++) {
        turn++;
        {
        char proposedSquare[2];
        int playerNumber = 9;
        int oppToken = 9;
        
        //line where the null character is suddenly entered
        whosTurn(turn, &playerNumber, &oppToken, proposedSquare);

        //print board
        printf("  abcd\n");
        printBoardRow(0, row0);
        printBoardRow(1, row1);
        printBoardRow(2, row2);
        printBoardRow(3, row3);
        }
    }
}
```

So i have an array with four element characters. and i pass 4 separate variables into a function that have nothing to do with the array. This function just sets specific numeric values for the variables depending on what two of the variables are.

And when the function returns and i print the array i mentioned before somehow, i have a null character replacing the first element (i.e arr[0]).

Why exactly is this? And how can i let it stop changing the first element into a null, i need to print the rows as it is

Comment: Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result. At a guess, `scanf("%s", proposedcoordinate);` is overflowing the buffer. You can only enter a one character string before overflowing that buffer.

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to work fine. I couldn't find where the problem is. One thing to note however, don't use `scanf("%s", proposedcoordinate)` to read input as it can cause a buffer overflow. Use `scanf("%1s", proposedcoordinate)` instead. Or better yet, avoid using `scanf()`. Use `fgets()` instead.